# Cabybara and Route Parameter s

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capybara

I have a Rails 3.0.10 app with some frontend forms that use route paramaters 
but I'm stuck with how to have capybara visit those dynamic paths.

routes.rb

```
match "weather/:region/:reporter" => "weather#new", :as => 'weather_report'
```

In my integration test I have the following:

```
visit weather_report_path(:region => 'north', :reporter => 'alex' )
```

this gives me a

```
NoMethodError:
       undefined method `weather_report' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x007f97084a3e08>
```

and if I tried to hard code the path in the integration test

ex: `visit 'weather/southeast/alex'`

capybara goes to the homepage...

Any guidance in right direction will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: so which framework you're using with Capybara? Rspec, Cucumber, Test::Unit... ?

Comment: I'm just using RSpec with Capybara.